# Is it possible to create Ctrl + shortcuts in Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

It would be nice if I could press Ctrl + S to save a Vim file like in Windows, rather than :wq. Is it possible to create shortcut keys in Vim?

Comment: [Simple googling does it.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345975/configure-shortcut-on-vim-to-save-file) If this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's absolutely possible. You just need to use
`<C-yourKey>` for map `ctrl+yourKey` key according to documentation [vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#control](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#control)